# How exactly did the government work with very large empires?

Tags: roman-empire, china, british-empire, government, rebellion

In planning my fictional worlds, I have come to wonder how exactly large empires worked, the main question being, how did they manage to keep control over such a large space in a manner that allowed them to remain stable, and not have the subdivisions try to act independently from the leader, or such.

I am aware nations such as America mainly do it through a mixture of most power being held higher up, and due to being more democratic. But how did this work with nations that were more totalitarian, or with monarchies?

So basically, how do large empires work to try to maintain absolute power despite size making it difficult to continue ruling over everything? Mainly thinking of places such as the Roman Empire, China, the British Empire, etc.

Comment: You've listed three examples spanning roughly 5000 years; the answers are going to be different by technology, by culture, by era, by context, etc.  I'd recommend that you start with preliminary research - perhaps [Imperialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperialism), and then ask a more precise question.

Comment: I was moreso asking general ideas of how they dealt with it rather than extreme specifics, because yeah, the specifics would vary greatly.

Comment: I hear you - but  a general answer may be useless; like relationships, the particulars are more important than the generals.    The current question is  kind of like asking, "how do I do surgery?" - the general answer, "you cut into someone" is going to lead to more deaths than cures.  You might read [hydralic empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_empire) and Satraps, and Roman Imperial, and British Imperial, then come back.   The overly simplified answer is "delegation & federation" - let the subordinate peoples be themselves and exact tribute3

Comment: Fair enough, now that I think about it, yeah, you're right. Sorry.

Comment: No apology required or appropriate - sometimes refining the question is even more valuable than answering it.  I wish I could summarize 5000 years of imperial rule in a couple of sentences, but...

Answer (score 4):

Well, the Romans wondered the same thing, and starting with Diocletian began splitting it into two empires with two (theoretically) co-equal Emperors, with the [Western half](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Roman_Empire) including western North Africa, Italy, and Western Europe, and the [Eastern half](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Empire#Early_history) including the Balkans, Egypt, and Asia.

This map shows the boundaries in 395 AD.
[image]

---

The Chinese only really reached that geographic expanse that posed this kind of problem during the Middle Ages. The [Tang Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tang_dynasty) mostly dealt with it by setting up a [powerful civil bureaucratic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_the_Tang_dynasty), and ceding most of their day-to-day power to it. So they weren't exactly "totalitarian", in the sense that most political decisions were being made by local career officials, not by the one true font of power off in the capital.

[image]

---

The British during their Imperial era mostly used a system of local Governors to act as the monarch's local representative and make any required quick decisions on their behalf. However, during most of this period the kingdom was being run under some form of [Constitutional Monarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutional_monarchy#England,_Scotland_and_the_United_Kingdom), with elected bodies like Parliament really having most of the power, not the Monarch.

It also helped greatly that communications during this era was much faster than in the Ancient and Middle Ages, and the British put a premium on improving it. This shows up in things like their obsession with Naval technology and their downright possessiveness of the [Suez Canal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suez_Canal#History_of_the_Suez_Canal) (which they did not build and originally had no ownership of).

Answer (score 2):

### Centralize power

Part of the reason the Chinese (Han-Ming) were able to achieve vast expanses was the tradition of strong bureaucracy and limited power of nobility. Exams and merit-based officeholder selection kept this viable in the long-term. By contrast, Western European courts were entrenched in centuries-long rivalry with the aristocracy who boasted fortified positions in their castles and maintained regional autonomy. This meant that the royal courts had their fiscal incomes diluted. Similarly, with the Japanese Empire, a strong sense of national identity accelerated its concentration of power at the central level and arguably facilitating its territorial reach. Flattening the nobility took decades not centuries like in Europe.

### Soft power

This makes for a convenient segway to another subtle yet key element to governing a large territory for long periods of time: cultural cohesion. Again using China as an example, although it was annexed repeatedly by northern Steppe powers, it was the refined soft power of the Chinese Han that persisted in the following centuries. Groups that annexed China, Manchurians and Mongolians, became to a large extent "Sinofied" during their reign. An extensive literary corpus, civil engineering and state planning capacities may ensure that even if your fictional empire is temporarily overthrown, its "DNA" will not be lost. Many still contend that China has the oldest continuous civilization despite these interruptions in the nation's sovereignty.

### Learn from past mistakes

I would caveat that while China has all the above virtues, it was still prone to major issues in policy implementation. Due to vast distances of the empire, there are many accounts of changes that were ordered by the central government only to be discovered, years later, that those orders were never carried out. China never really resolved this issue, and depending on the technological level for your setting, this may need careful calibrating to avoid. Other issues include inefficiencies stemming from the fractal design of the bureaucracy. There were multiple contending bodies across central and local nodes in the hierarchy over the same projects. An example being irrigation/water: a general central government water project body, a local government water project body and a central government water project body designed specifically to align the local body to the central governments interests. It can become very nebulous very quickly.

Comment: Hi. This looks like a promising answer. Adding sources / links would improve it.

Comment: Japan is of course a little more complicated, depending on how you look at the Shogun vs the Emperor.